# R1 to R1 MATLAB function using values from vector

Tags: matlab, function, vector

I have some efficiency problems in my code that I could solve easily saving the values of an R->R function in a table/vector, and using the vector to give the results instead of computing the function expression every time. 
Is there an easy way to do it or I have to implement it for example using "find"?

Comment: Can you explain a bit further what you are doing? What does R->R mean in your context?

Comment: Real numbers to real numbers function.

Comment: If you want specific help, you should post a simple, repeatable code snippet that others can use to replicate the situation. see [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more suggestions

Comment: @gerardpc: StackOverflow doesn't support Tex and many of it's denizens aren't versed in mathematical notation, so it's usually best to use words and code (and images if necessary) to explain your problem and ask your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `interp1` would do what you want, using the `'nearest'` interpolation flag - check the documentation